# Is there a way to get Vite.js to use axios.options?

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3, vite, node-http-proxy

I am in the process of moving everything from Vue CLI to Vite.
Right now, I have everything that was in vue.config.js to be in vite.config.ts of the new project. Every axios call that was proxy works except axios.options.

I've checked in my [Browser > Inspect > Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOM3y.png) and it shows that it is a status 204 for this options call.
My backend service did not detect any options call.

Does Vite.js proxy not support options calls? If so, is there a workaround for this?
I think I have to change something in vite.config.ts > server > proxy > configure but I am unsure.

EDIT: My backend endpoint that accepts the OPTIONS call determines which HTTPs methods is allowed. There are methods I allow for certain context.

Comment: You should never be making direct `OPTIONS` requests. Your browser does that automatically for pre-flighted cross-origin requests. And if you're using a proxy, there should not be a need for those in any case

Comment: My backend service has an endpoint that accepts OPTIONS request to determine which methods are allowed given a user's context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned off preflight for cors in vite.config.ts and it worked.

```
cors: {
  preflightContinue: true
},
```